# I need to delete a lot of users from a table but leave only a selected few

Tags: mysql

I need to run a query to delete thousands of spam users.

I am thinking this might work.

```
DELETE FROM `d9pg9_k2_users` WHERE `userID` is > 297
```

Will this work or will it ruin everything?

Comment: How could we possibly know?

Comment: `WHERE userID > 297`

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. All the user id's I want to delete are greater than 297 and this is the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run
`SELECT * FROM [d9pg9_k2_users] where [userID] > 297`
this is what the `DELETE` statement will delete.

Comment: So run SELECT * FROM [d9pg9_k2_users] where [userID] > 297

Comment: then run DELETE FROM `d9pg9_k2_users` WHERE `userID` is > 297

Comment: Run the select, if you are happy to heve EVERYTHING in the results from the select deleted, then run the delete. The select is your sense check.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[d9pg9_k2_users] where [userID] >297 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, I used MS SQL syntax, missed the mysql tag. Try SELECT * FROM d9pg9_k2_users where userID > 297 ... mysql uses backticks rather than brackets but since none of the names contains spaces I don't think either are required.